# Bug in syntax highlighter for VB.NET

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

See this thread where I got this issue: [Cannot add rows to DataTable from another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055035/cannot-add-rows-to-datatable-from-another-thread).

And specifically my solution to it, where it says

```vb
_dt.Rows.RemoveAt(_dt.Rows.Count - 1)
```

In VB.NET `rem` denotes a comment, an equivalent of `'`, but it should do some syntax analysis, because not everything that comes after string `rem` is a comment.

Comment: [Raise an issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/entry) for prettify.

Comment: @DanielFischer: As far as I got it, StackOverflow uses prettify for syntax highlight under the hood. If so, their devs probably have more weight on google-code than me, when submitting the issue - so higher chance it gets resolved quickly - and they get notified, cause it's them who ultimately will be replacing this component with newer version.

Comment: I'm taking a peek, it looks like this is fixed in the latest version of prettify [here's ours](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/DyLqE/) and [here's the latest](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/u5LJ3/) to play with...looks like we need to update but need to see what if anything it breaks.

Comment: @NickCraver: Looks like the latest is not quite correct either. `Rem Comment here!` should be same color as `'Comment`, and it's not.

Comment: @Neolisk, the trick for making it stop commenting everything after `'` is to put `<!-- language: lang-vb -->` before the code. It's not properly recognizing the language, and is trying to find the closing quote

Comment: @DanielFischer, https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=254

Comment: @SeanCheshire: thanks for a workaround - I honestly did not know about it. Also this `<!-- language -->` trick looks like something I need to remember - it's not in the editor's UI. It still does not resolve the issue with rem commenting until the end of line. But please go ahead and post it as an answer (since it resolved part of the problem for now). So if not completely resolved by end of bounty, you'll get half of it, plus my upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick for making it stop commenting everything after ' is to put `<!-- language: lang-vb -->` before the code. It's not properly recognizing the language, and is trying to find the closing quote

The issue is raised (but feel free to add comments): https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=254

Comment: I left my upvote there. +1

Comment: Thanks for submitting this issue. (even though nobody looked at it yet at google code)

Answer (score 0):

We have pulled in the latest prettify source including all of the plugins.  The issue you have pointed out appears to be still present in the latest version of prettify.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Guess not many care about VB.NET. Hope it gets fixed one day... :)

Comment: Has someone (preferably someone from SE) raised an issue for prettify about this?

Comment: @geoff , reported fixed: **Fixed in r228 which will be included in a forthcoming release**.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't Stackoverflow switch to use [sunlight.js](http://sunlightjs.com/demo.html#vb)?

It seems to be well built and documented. Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809582/are-there-any-google-code-prettify-alternatives-that-automate-syntaxhighlighti).